# Switch to Solr - getting Unknown Field

Tags: solr

Using Sitecore 8.1 Update and Solr 6.0.1

After switching to Solr, I am having indexing problems. Sometime the index rebuild works, and sometimes it fails with a variety of:

```
ERROR: [doc=sitecore://core/{31a3a929-c599-4dd3-91a6-f4a9487cc8b7}?lang=da&ver=1&ndx=sitecore_core_index] unknown field 'parameters'
```

for several different fields. And also:

```
ERROR: [doc=sitecore://core/{31a3a929-c599-4dd3-91a6-f4a9487cc8b7}?lang=da&ver=1&ndx=sitecore_core_index] unknown field 'parameters'
```

I can manually update the `schema.xml`, but when I rebuild, it finds a new fields.

Shouldn't a new install of Solr just work?

Comment: Looks like you’re a bit higher than the recommended Solr version: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897

Comment: Have you configured schema.xml according to documentation? Go to solr logs for more details. It is expected to work. I'm using 6.1.0 without problems for Sitecore 8.2

Comment: I think I have, but I certainly suspect thats the source of the problem. Im not sure how I can tell if its configured correctly?

Comment: @BartłomiejMucha Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: @EthanSchofer, this going anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this had to do with the Solr configs, particularly schema.xml. I believe I had the wrong version. To solve:

1. I reviewed the Solr compatability table: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897
2. I got a copy of the Solr install files to make sure I had the correct raw schema.xml (Which was called managedschema with my version of solr).
3. I very meticulously followed the Solr set up instructions
   https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/walkthrough_setting_up_solr
   Including the extra steps listed in the compatability table

After doing this, solr came up.

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure your `schema.xml` for each core. You can do that by going to **Control Panel** and in the **Indexing** tab click **Generate the Solr Schema** file. Sitecore will add field definitions into `schema.xml` file.
It doesn't work out of the box.

[Here is a very good, official walkthrouht about setting up a Solr for Sitecore](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/walkthrough_setting_up_solr).